# How to set a fixed distance between section and the text in a twocolumn document

Tags: two-column, sections-paragraphs

I would like to know how to set a fixd distance bewteen the title of a section and corresponding text.

```
 \documentclass[twocolumn,prl,nobalancelastpage,aps,10pt]{revtex4-1}
 %\documentclass[rmp,preprint]{revtex4-1}
 \usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx,bm,times}
\usepackage{subfig}
\graphicspath{}
\begin{document}

\title{Electrical resistance of Cu, Ni and Ge in the range $120K$ - $400K$}

\author{Andrea Angeletti}

\affiliation{}

\begin{abstract} 
\end{abstract}

\date{\today}

\maketitle

\section{INTRODUCTION}
 text
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Related question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481966/too-much-space-between-section-and-text-in-a-twocolumn-document

Comment: Easy solution is to use \unskip to remove the default spacing and \vspace{...} to add your own.